# Does Group() in pyparsing requires a post processing step to generate a structure specific to the langauge being parsed

Tags: python, pyparsing

This is an [extension of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934552/translating-an-ebnf-grammar-to-pyparsing-give-error?noredirect=1#comment109547446_61934552). I have written the `pyparsing` code as one-to-one translation of grammar.

My DSL :

```
response:success
response:success AND extension:php OR extension:css
response:sucess AND (extension:php OR extension:css)
time >= 2020-01-09
time >= 2020-01-09 AND response:success OR os:windows
NOT reponse:success
response:success AND NOT os:windows
```

EBNF Grammar fro above DSL:

```
<expr> ::= <or>
<or> ::= <and> (" OR " <and>)*
<and> ::= <unary> ((" AND ") <unary>)*
<unary> ::= " NOT " <unary> | <equality>
<equality> ::=  (<word> ":" <word>) | <comparison>
<comparison> ::= "(" <expr> ")" | (<word> (" > " | " >= " | " < " | " <= ") <word>)+
<word> ::= ("a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g"
                      | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n"
                      | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u"
                      | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z")+
```

Now I can get a list of tokens. the next step is to generate some sort of ast/structure so that I can generate the code from each node type?

After reading some examples on `pyparsing` i think I got a vague idea of how to approach this:

1) I can use `Group()` to group together relevant structure important for code generation and each grouping will probably represent a node in ast.
2) Along with `Group()` i can use `setParseAction()` to directly encode the python representation of my node object during the parsing phase itself instead of generating a structure first.

```
My approach in code:
AND = Keyword('AND')
OR  = Keyword('OR')
NOT = Keyword('NOT')
word = Word(alphanums+'_')




expr = Forward()
Comparison = Literal('(') + expr + Literal(')')  + OneOrMore(word + ( Literal('>') | Literal('>=') | Literal('<') | Literal('<=')) + word)
Equality = Group((word('searchKey') + Literal(':') + word('searchValue')) | Comparison)
Unary = Forward()
unaryNot = NOT + Unary
Unary << (unaryNot | Equality)
And = Group(Unary + ZeroOrMore(AND + Unary))
Or = And + ZeroOrMore(OR + And)

expr << Or



class AndNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens.asList()

    def query(self):
        pass #generate the relevant elastic search query here?


class ExactMatchNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ExactMatchNode>"
    def query(self):
        pass #generate the relevant elasticsearch query here?


Equality.setParseAction(ExactMatchNode)




Q1 = '''response:200 AND time:22 AND rex:32 OR NOT demo:good'''
result = expr.parseString(Q1)

print(result.dump())
```

This is my output:

```
[[<ExactMatchNode>, 'AND', <ExactMatchNode>, 'AND', <ExactMatchNode>], 'OR', ['NOT', <ExactMatchNode>]]
[0]:
  [<ExactMatchNode>, 'AND', <ExactMatchNode>, 'AND', <ExactMatchNode>]
[1]:
  OR
[2]:
  ['NOT', <ExactMatchNode>]
```

I am lost at this point as in how does this represents a tree structure? ex.

```
[<ExactMatchNode>, 'AND', <ExactMatchNode>, 'AND', <ExactMatchNode>]
```

should be like this instead?

```
[AND [<ExactMatchNode>, <ExactMatchNode>,  <ExactMatchNode>]]
```

*I guess this could be done in `setParseAction` but I am not sure is this the right direction? or i should start modifying my grammar at this point. End goal of this DSL is to translate the given query to `elasticsearch` json querying language.*

**EDIT:**
**After trying out some things this is what I have:**

```
class NotNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.negatearg = tokens
        #print(f'**** \n {self.negatearg} \n +++')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'( NOT-> {self.negatearg} )'

class AndNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.conds = tokens[0][::2]
        #print(f'**** \n {tokens} \n +++')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'( AND-> {self.conds} )'

    def generate_query(self):
        result = [cond.generate_query() for cond in self.conds]
        return result


class ExactMatchNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens[0]
        #print(f'**** \n {tokens} \n +++')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<ExactMatchNode {self.tokens.searchKey}={self.tokens.searchValue}>"

    def generate_query(self):
        return {
                'term' : { self.tokens[0]: self.tokens[2]}
        }


unaryNot.setParseAction(NotNode)
Equality.setParseAction(ExactMatchNode)
And.setParseAction(AndNode)
```

I can now use `<some node object>.generate_query()` to get a query .

but one wierd thing i notice in my output below is:

```
[( AND-> [<ExactMatchNode response=200>, <ExactMatchNode time=22>, <ExactMatchNode rex=32>] ), 'OR', ( AND-> [( NOT-> ['NOT', <ExactMatchNode demo=good>] )] )]
```

second `AND->` appended before `NOT` node.

***My question is still the same, is this even the correct way of using pyparsing or I missed something obvious and going in the wrong direction?***

Comment: Using parse actions to build an AST is the way I have pretty much settled on performing this task. When doing so, the Groups are not really needed any more - your AST classes are taking care of the group structuring for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching node classes using setParseAction is the best way I have found to build an AST from a hierchical grammar. You will probably not need the Group constructs if you use this method. The reason you are getting the second And is because your parser *always* produces an AndNode, even if there is only one operand with no additional `AND operand`.

You can expand your And expression to only attach the AndNode parse action class if there is an `operand AND operand` (and likewise for NOT and OR), something like:

```
And = (Unary + OneOrMore(AND + Unary)).addParseAction(AndNode) | Unary
Or = (And + OneOrMore(OR + And)).addParseAction(OrNode) | And
```

This is how pyparsing's infixNotation handles these kinds of operators.

My version of your parser, using infixNotation (I think the classes are almost all the same, maybe I tweaked the NotNode definition):

```
"""
<expr> ::= <or>
<or> ::= <and> (" OR " <and>)*
<and> ::= <unary> ((" AND ") <unary>)*
<unary> ::= " NOT " <unary> | <equality>
<equality> ::=  (<word> ":" <word>) | <comparison>
<comparison> ::= "(" <expr> ")" | (<word> (" > " | " >= " | " < " | " <= ") <word>)+
<word> ::= ("a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g"
                      | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n"
                      | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u"
                      | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z")+
"""

import pyparsing as pp

NOT, AND, OR = map(pp.Keyword, "NOT AND OR".split())

word = ~(NOT | AND | OR) + pp.Word(pp.alphas.lower() + '-_')
date = pp.Regex(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
operand = word | date

class ExactMatchNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ExactMatchNode>"
    def query(self):
        pass #generate the relevant elasticsearch query here?

class ComparisonNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ComparisonNode>"
    def query(self):
        pass #generate the relevant elasticsearch query here?

class NotNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.negatearg = tokens[0][1]
        #print(f'**** \n {self.negatearg} \n +++')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'( NOT-> {self.negatearg} )'

class AndNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.conds = tokens[0][::2]
        #print(f'**** \n {tokens} \n +++')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'( AND-> {self.conds} )'

    def generate_query(self):
        result = [cond.generate_query() for cond in self.conds]
        return result

class OrNode:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.conds = tokens[0][::2]
        #print(f'**** \n {tokens} \n +++')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'( OR-> {self.conds} )'

    def generate_query(self):
        result = [cond.generate_query() for cond in self.conds]
        return result

expr = pp.infixNotation(operand,
    [
    (':', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ExactMatchNode),
    (pp.oneOf("> >= < <="), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ComparisonNode),
    (NOT, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, NotNode),
    (AND, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, AndNode),
    (OR, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, OrNode),
    ])


expr.runTests("""\
    response:success
    response:success AND extension:php OR extension:css
    response:sucess AND (extension:php OR extension:css)
    time >= 2020-01-09
    time >= 2020-01-09 AND response:success OR os:windows
    NOT reponse:success
    response:success AND NOT os:windows
    """)
```

prints

```
response:success
[<ExactMatchNode>]

response:success AND extension:php OR extension:css
[( OR-> [( AND-> [<ExactMatchNode>, <ExactMatchNode>] ), <ExactMatchNode>] )]

response:sucess AND (extension:php OR extension:css)
[( AND-> [<ExactMatchNode>, ( OR-> [<ExactMatchNode>, <ExactMatchNode>] )] )]

time >= 2020-01-09
[<ComparisonNode>]

time >= 2020-01-09 AND response:success OR os:windows
[( OR-> [( AND-> [<ComparisonNode>, <ExactMatchNode>] ), <ExactMatchNode>] )]

NOT reponse:success
[( NOT-> <ExactMatchNode> )]

response:success AND NOT os:windows
[( AND-> [<ExactMatchNode>, ( NOT-> <ExactMatchNode> )] )]
```

Comment: thankyou so much for such a detailed explanation. I was spending most of my time for past few days to study parsing in general, grammar construction, and about playing with pyparsing examples on Github to understand the bits. I figured it would be best if I tried my best to understand everything before I add some comments or ask anything further. Can I delay accepting the answer until I try it on my own machine and have understood everything ?